# Best way to go between private on-premises network and kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, service-node-port-range

I have setup an on-premises Kubernetes cluster, and I want to be ensure that my services that are not in Kubernetes, but exist on a separate class B are able to consume those services that have migrated to Kubernetes. There's a number of ways of doing this by all accounts and I'm looking for the simplest one.

Ingress + controller seems to be the one favoured - and it's interesting because of the virtual hosts and HAProxy implementation. But where I'm getting confused is how to set up the Kubernetes service:

We've not a great deal of choice - ClusterIP won't be sufficient to expose it to the outside, or NodePort. LoadBalancer seems to be a simpler, cut down way of switching between network zones - and although there are OnPrem solutions (metalLB), seems to be far geared towards cloud solutions.

But if I stick with NodePort, then my entry into the network is going to be on a non-standard port number, and I would prefer it to be over standard port; particuarly if running a percentage of traffic for that service over non-kube, and the rest over kubernetes (for testing purposes, I'd like to monitor the traffic over a period of time before I bite the bullet and move 100% of traffic for the given microservice to kubernetes). In that case it would be better those services would be available across the same port (almost always 80 because they're standard REST micro-services). More than that, if I have to re-create the service for whatever reason, I'm pretty sure the port will change, and then all traffic will not be able to enter the Kubernetes cluster and that's a frightening proposition.

What are the suggested ways of handling communication between existing on-prem and Kubernetes cluster (also on prem, different IP/subnet)?
Is there anyway to get traffic coming in without changing the network parameters (class B's the respective networks are on), and not being forced to use NodePort?

Answer (score 0):

NodePort service type may be good at stage or dev environments. But i recommend you to go with LoadBalancer type service (Nginx ingress controller is one).  The advantage for this over other service types are

1. You can use standard port (Rather random Nodeport generated by your kubernetes).
2. Your service is load balanced. (Load balancing will be taken care by ingress controller).
3. Fixed port (it will not change unless you modify something in ingress object).

Comment: Bearing in mind it's an on-premises setup do you still recommend LoadBalancer? My understanding is that depending on the Ingress-controller, load balancing will occur regardless - e.g.: HAProxyIngressController, his job is to set up the config for the HAProxy instance which will then route directly to the pods and bypass the service, thus negating the need for the LoadBalancer part of the service, or am i barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: RE: "LoadBalancer type service ( Nginx ingress controller is one)" without wishing to appear argumentative, but NginxIngressController is an example of an IngressController, and we need to create an Ingress instance for it. It is not an example of a Service which is simply, AFAIK, an abstraction of endpoints and not much more - albeit subsequent service definitions beyond ClusterIP are a superset of the previous.